# Device Policy to Restrict users to not allow any app installation?

Tags: android

I have an app and I want users to only use that app on the device, for that i need to restrict any other app installation.

I was checking the `DeviceManager` `policy` API but i couldn't find something that totally restrict users from downloading apps or sideloading them.

Is this feasible to do in non rooted device?

Comment: Really? Does your company provide the devices? Because if not, then this is not realistic

Comment: actually internal use app, devices are company owned

Comment: Okay then you could create your own Launcher and have your app listed there ONLY! then remove any other launchers

Comment: also something to restrict fb,whatsapp on user device?? is it possible note devices are being given free internet so we are trying to limit the data usage

Comment: I wonder if you can have a background code that runs and checks if WhatsApp, Facebook etc are installed then uninstalls them;